# Unable to access Wordpress API and Plugins API on OpenBSD 7.3

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, mariadb, openbsd

I just finished setup my web server on OpenBSD 7.3 by installing php-7.4, nginx, and MariaDB. the Wordpress admin looks fine but when i check the debugging, it show several error like this:

```
GET http://d2salfytceyqoe.cloudfront.net/wpml33-products.json
http_request_failed

POST https://api.wordpress.org/plugins/update-check/1.1/
http_request_failed

POST http://139.180.143.200/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron=1681964903.0030410289764404296875
error getting response code, most likely a stopped request
```

I assume somehow OpenBSD blocked them, but when i check it by nslookup it working fine

```
nslookup api.wordpress.org
Server:         108.61.10.10
Address:        108.61.10.10#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   api.wordpress.org
Address: 198.143.164.251
```

another problem is when i change my default url site from my server ip to my domain it just giving me error. i check the logs nothing found, i set my nginx correctly and i check my domain with https://dnschecker.org/ it point out to my server ip. Any help please?

Comment: Try to run this command on your server: `curl --head http://d2salfytceyqoe.cloudfront.net/wpml33-products.json` What do you see?

Answer (score 0):

In OpenBSD, https runs Wordpress within chroot. So the chroot blocks access to services like DNS. You need to copy the config files inside the chroot:

```
mkdir -p /var/www/etc
cp /etc/resolv.conf /var/www/etc
cp /etc/hosts /var/www/etc
```

In my case, I had to add the nameservers to `resolv.conf`:

```
nameserver 1.1.1.1
nameserver 9.9.9.9
```